# Why are my links in html ul li not working?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, href

I'm currently trying to build my first website (homework). For my dropdown menu, I used Dev Ed's tutorial for a dropdown menu, and it is working except that I can't click on the links in the dropdown bits. 
(the mouse coursor still changes into that hand-symbol though)

How can I fix this?

```css
nav {
  grid-column: 1/5;
  background: #2E3045;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav a,
button {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  font-family: Bahnschrift, sans-serif;
  color: #DFB830;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* horizontal-menu */

.menu {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}


/* styling horizontal-menu buttons */

.dropdown button,
.dd-buttons {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.menu button:hover,
.dd-buttons:hover {
  color: #ECEEFF;
}


/* styling the dropdown arrow */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .menu img {
    max-width: 7px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  .menu img {
    max-width: 15px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}


/* dropdown list */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #DFB830;
  margin-top: 8px;
  min-width: 150%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}


/* styling dropdown menu list items */

.dropdown li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 250%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.dropdown a {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: #2E3045;
}


/* when hovering over dropdown list */

.dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #E9CF72;
}

.dropdown button:focus+ul {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<!------------------------ menu ------------------------>
<nav>
  <div class="menu">
    <button class="dd-buttons"><a href="https://www.youthduo.com/" target="_blank">YouthDuo</a></button>
    <button class="dd-buttons"><a href="https://www.galacticspirit.com/home.php" target="_blank">Galactic Spirit</a></button>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button>Feng Shui <img src="images/dropdown icon.png"></button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Feng Shui Basics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CD's and DVD's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Books and EBooks</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button>Color Alchemy <img src="images/dropdown icon.png"></button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="LIC.html" target="_blank">Living in Color</a></li>
        <li><a href="GT.html">Guided Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="CAB.html">Jami Lin's Products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `pointer-events:none`

```
.dropdown ul {
    position: absolute; 
    background: #DFB830;
    margin-top: 8px;
    min-width: 150%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
```